# Flutter plugin fails to build on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, google-nearby-messages

I've installed [flutter_nearby_messages_api](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_nearby_messages_api) and there is an error when building the iOS app:

```
 Failed to build iOS app
[        ] Error (Xcode): Multiple commands produce '/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Assets.car'
           
[   +1 ms] Could not build the application for the simulator.
[        ] Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
```

I've even tried to rebuild the flutter plugin myself and got the same error after adding `s.dependency 'NearbyMessages'` to the `<plugin>.podspec` file. I'm not an iOS developer, but i think it has to do with CocoaPods somehow.

This is in the Podfile.lock of the flutter plugin:

```
PODS:
  - Flutter (1.0.0)
  - flutter_nearby_messages_api (0.0.5):
    - Flutter
    - NearbyMessages
  - GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.2):
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
  - GoogleNetworkingUtilities (1.2.2):
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
  - GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.2)
  - GoogleUtilitiesLegacy (1.3.2):
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
  - NearbyMessages (1.1.1):
    - GoogleInterchangeUtilities (~> 1.2)
    - GoogleNetworkingUtilities (~> 1.2)
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
    - GoogleUtilitiesLegacy (~> 1.3)
```

I hope someone can help me, i would have added a issue but the flutter plugin is not on a public repository.

Comment: is it necessary to use real device? maybe your simulator cannot use this package

Comment: @Nguyenfamily unfortunately i cannot test that, because my iPhone 8 cannot connect to my Macbook anymore.. i updated Xcode and the iPhone to iOS 16.4 (latest version). but still can't connect. Anyway when trying to build with `flutter build ipa` it throughs the same error.